# Table of contents, I want the page number top right and no "CONTENTS" header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I want my contents page to have the page number in the top right hand corner but without the header saying "CONTENTS". I have tried multiple things I've found online, for example:

1.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{iopart}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\Large\textbf{Title}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\markboth{}{}
```

gives an output of

[image]

Or alternatively

2.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{iopart}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\Large\textbf{Title}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\markboth{}{}
```

gives an output of:

[image]

but with the page number in the bottom centre of the page.

So I basically want a combination of the two. Any advice would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

OP here. Found a way to do it in case anyone is interested.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\Large\textbf{Title}
\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % this removes an optional horizontal line below the header
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{} % Not required if left blank. Same for \rfoot and \lfoot
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\markboth{}{}
```

Comment: please make your example more complete by providing `\end{document}` and all other needed lines of code